# Not getting any error message or content from cURL

Tags: php, curl

Using the code below I'm not getting any kind of error or content.

I'm interested in getting content of my website http://www.aptamitra.in.

```
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
//$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.aptamitra.in" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
var_dump($content);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);  // iam getting response here.
curl_close ( $ch );
```

The array which i get using  `var_dump($content)` `print_r($response)` is shown below

```
bool(false)

Array
(
    [url] => http://www.aptamitra.in/
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 4956
    [request_size] => 4984
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 20
    [total_time] => 0.452
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.124
    [redirect_time] => 0.328
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 1080
    [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [local_port] => 52230
)
```

I don't know why there is no content.

Comment: You are receiving a 302 redirect, hence no content, but you have CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION turned on, which should follow that redirect. Puzzling!

Comment: @sherif,yes im not getting content or error message

Comment: echo curl_error($ch); paste before curl_exec(); and know the error

Comment: yes @jedifans it is on

Comment: What happens if you try to load `http://www.aptamitra.in/` instead of `http://www.aptamitra.in` ? (So, with the / at the end)

Comment: @jothi,i have put echo curl_error($ch); but no error

Comment: @jedifans,nothing been changed by adding http://www.aptamitra.in/

Comment: It appears to be connecting to 127.0.0.1:1080, which is detecting that it isn't the right hostname and redirecting there. Do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: @jedifans that does not matter. If the client does not include the trailing `/` and the server wants the trailing `/`, it will simply redirect the client to a new URL with the trailing `/` on it. Which seems to be the case in this situation

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I was attempting to eliminate the 302 to see if the follow location option was the bit having trouble. As you pointed out, curl_error would be better to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) documentation:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Your call to `var_dump($content);` is showing `bool(false)`, which means `curl_exec()` is failing. That is why you are not getting any response content.  Use [`curl_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and/or [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to find out why it is failing.

One thing I do notice is `curl_getinfo()` is reporting `[redirect_count] => 20`.  That is a **lot** of redirects.  The server is likely getting stuck in an endless redirect loop and `curl_exec()` decides to fail after awhile. See `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`.  Check if the error number being reported is `CURLE_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Comment: @RemyLebeu, the error is Curl error: Maximum (20) redirects followed

Comment: @user5405873 well, there you go then. Now you have to find each URL the server is redirecting to, and make sure curl is redirecting correctly. This is either a server bug redirecting to the same URL over and over even if curl is requesting it, or more likely curl is not sending something the server is expecting so it uses redirects to try to force it.

Comment: ,what you are saying is 100% correct. it is a server error what should i do now.

Comment: ,i got my solution through you.

Answer (score 0):

hope this works

```
 $options = array(
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
  CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0', //set user agent
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
  CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
  CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
);

$ch      = curl_init("http://www.aptamitra.in/");
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );    
echo curl_exec( $ch );    
curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: iam getting the same response as above code(my code),nothing has been changed

Answer (score 0):

using the following I was able to print the page content OK.

```
function mmcurl( $url=NULL, $data=array(), $options=NULL ){

    /* Download cacert.pem and change path here to suit */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
    $cookiejar=tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), '_cookiejar_' );                    


    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
    }
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

    if( $options->cookie ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookiejar );
    }
    if( $options->post ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $data ) );
    }
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl ),
        'cookie'    =>  $cookiejar
    );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}



$url='http://www.aptamitra.in';
$data=array();
$options=new StdClass;
$options->post=false;
$options->cookie=true;


$res=mmcurl( $url, $data, $options );
echo '<pre>',print_r($res,true),'</pre>';
```

Comment: your code output looks like(i do have cacert.pem) this

Comment: ? the code returns the html for the given url - you could go on to load that into DOMDocument if there was further processing to be done quite easily

Comment: ,yes you are right 100% it is a server problem.  how can i fix it please help me.